# How To Send Numeric Value Without Quotes In Rest API Request Using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am creating a web site. In this web site , I have used a Rest API. Basically I send a JSON request using JavaScript and Ajax. Then I have created a HTML form to get inputs. Now I want to get numeric value from the form and I want to use that value as variable in the JSON request.

Here is HTML form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

                        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="label-control">Origin City</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="OriginLocation" value="CMB" id="OriginLocation">
                            </div>      
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="label-control">Adults</label>
                                <select name="adults" class="form-control" id="adults">
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                            <center><a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search Flight Data</a></center>

                        </div>

                    </form>
```

I want to use "adults" as a variable in this Quantity. Then I have tried like below. When I try like this , it sends request with quotes. But , I want to send this value qithout quotes.

How can I do this ??

Here is the JSON Request.

```
"TravelerInfoSummary": {
    "SeatsRequested": [1],
    "AirTravelerAvail": [{
    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{
        "Code": "ADT", //adt cnn inf
        "Quantity": adults // What I want - "Quantity": 1 and What I get "Quantity": "1"
    },
    {
        "Code": "CNN",
        "Quantity": 1
    }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Here is the JavaScript , Ajax that I used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function(e) {
                        var adults = $('#adults').val();

                         var JSONObj = {
                         "TravelerInfoSummary": {
                                    "SeatsRequested": [1],
                                  "AirTravelerAvail": [{
                                      "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{
                                         "Code": "ADT", //adt cnn inf
                                            "Quantity": 1
                                       },
                                       {
                                        "Code": "CNN",
                                            "Quantity": 1
                                       },
                                       {
                                        "Code": "INF",
                                            "Quantity": 2
                                        }
                                       ]
                                    }]
                                }

                        };

                        var data = JSON.stringify(JSONObj);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v4.2.0/shop/flights?mode=live&limit=50&offset=1',
                            method: 'POST',
                            contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: data,
                            headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data);

                                    for (var v = 0; v <= 999; v++) {
                                    var row = $('<tr><td>' + data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].SequenceNumber + '</td><td>'
                                        + data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[0].FlightSegment[0].DepartureDateTime + '</td><td>'
                                    $('#tblData').append(row);}

                            },

                        });
                    });

    </script>
```

Comment: you can parse string into int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value="1"` means the value you'll get from `$('#adults').val()` will be *string `1`*. To turn it into *integer `1`* you use `parseInt`.

Like this:

```
...
"Quantity": parseInt(adults, 10) // always supply radix 10 for safety
...
```

`JSON.stringify` will now know the value of `"Quantity"` is a Number and serialize it accordingly.

Comment: It Worked !! Thank You !! :D